# AVR C - How does the const qualifier behaves in a look up table declaration?

Tags: c, avr

I found the following code in a forum and i was wondering how does the `const` qualifier behaves in it?

```
const uint8_t data[] = { 15, 3, 41, 76, 2, 9, 5 };

val = data[5];
```

Now, as i understand the `const` qualifier makes the variable `data[]` read-only so that, in this example, the contents of the array can't be modified.
What confuses me is that the qualifier is being applied to an array, which is a pointer so the contents of the array can be modified but the pointer itself can't.

Am i right?, or is the content of the array read-only?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is an array name a pointer?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1641957/is-an-array-name-a-pointer)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> an array, which is a pointer

No, *no*, **no**. Arrays are **not** pointers. A pointer is an address (usually 4 or 8 bytes on current desktop systems). An array is a sequence of contiguous objects in memory, one after the other.

In most expressions, arrays *decay* to pointers: when you use the name of an array, it is implicitly converted to a pointer to its first element. But that is just a conversion, just like `1` converts to `1.0` when initialising a variable of type `double`.

Given the above, the answer is clear: `data` is an array of 7 objects of type `const uint8_t`, which means its contents cannot be modified. In expressions, `data` will implicitly convert to type `const uint8_t *` (pointer to constant 8-bit unsigned integer).